# Windows mobile BIP1300 IC card reader

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, windows-mobile, smartcard-reader

I have a bip 1300 hand terminal. I'm workin on a sale application. But I cant find a solution for readin card informations from IC card port . Anyone can explain how is this workin on BIP 1300. Can i read all information on card chip or just number ,date and name ?

How can i get customers password for matching it with password on Chip.

Main purpose readin data from IC card port and get them on my screen now i am just gettin numbers but they dont have any meaning for me

thanks for interest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to process Chip-pin Credit Card, You can't get customer's password.
You have to use the EMV L2 Software to do it. You will not have direct control over the validation process. Ask your supplier for the software. You would be able to retrieve Name, Credit card number, Validity date, etc ... read also the ISO/IEC 7816-3 protocol so you can understand what all those numbers means.